# Interpreting binary string as integer in python

Tags: python

I am reading a file (disk images and /dev/sda and likes) in python using binary mode. I am reading the first sector (512 bytes) and am trying to print disk information (ref: [Wikipedia Articles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_boot_record)).

To interpret things like the 32bit LBA of first absolute sector in the partition, I am doing things like -

```
def int32(bytes):
    return int(bytes[3]<<24|bytes[2]<<16|bytes[1]<<8|bytes[0])

def int16(bytes):
    return int(bytes[1]<<8|bytes[0])
```

`print('LBA:',int32(partitionEntry[8:12]))`

Is there native wat to do this in python? As typecasting `intVar=(int*)someBasePointer` in C

---

Added after marking as answered:

Is there a way to do this for odd bit structure? Like the [CHS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_boot_record#Partition_table_entries). C (cylinders) are 10 bits 8 bits from one byte and 2 from the other byte. My current approach for this is

```
def getCHS(bytes):
    c=bytes[1]&3<<8|bytes[2]
    h=bytes[0]
    s=bytes[1]&63
    return {'c':c,'s':s,'h':h}
```

Comment: Look at `struct` module in Python: http://docs.python.org/library/struct.html (examples: http://docs.python.org/library/struct.html#examples)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want the [`struct.unpack()`](http://docs.python.org/library/struct.html#struct.unpack) function.

```
import struct

def int32(some_bytes):
    return struct.unpack("i", some_bytes)[0]

def int16(some_bytes):
    return struct.unpack("h", some_bytes)[0]
```

If you're reading from a system that uses different endian values than the current system, you may need to specify the endianness in the format string as well.

(`i` and `h` are the signed int versions; if you want unsigned, use `I` and `H`)

Comment: Thank you. This works! I am looking into the documentation of struct. Is there a way to do this for odd bit structure? Like the CHS. C (cylinders) are 10 bits 8 bits from one byte and 2 from the other byte.

Comment: `struct` doesn't support partial bytes, no. You'll still have to do that manipulation yourself.

Comment: Thanks. That is useful to know outright than wondering if I am reinventing the wheel.

Answer (score 3):

For simple 1-, 2-, or 4-byte fields, your best bet may be [`struct.unpack`](http://docs.python.org/library/struct.html#struct.unpack).  Try something like:

```
def int32(bytes):
    return struct.unpack("i", bytes[:4])[0]
```

You might need to specify the endian with `"<i"` or `">i"` as the format string.

However, more unusual field widths require masking and/or bitshifting.  Your approach works well; alternatively, you could unpack an unsigned type of sufficient size, but it doesn't save much work:

```
def getCHS(bytes):
    h, r = struct.unpack("BH", bytes[:3])
    c = r & 0x3F
    s = r >> 10
    return {'c':c,'s':s,'h':h}
```

Comment: Note that this will return a tuple with one value, not the individual value. Also, silently slicing the input set of bytes isn't going to buy you much and *will* mask accidental errors that input more data. It'd be better to just assume you're getting a 4-byte string input.

Comment: Thank you. This works! I am looking into the documentation of struct. Is there a way to do this for odd bit structure? Like the CHS. C (cylinders) are 10 bits 8 bits from one byte and 2 from the other byte.

Comment: @Amber: Good point; I've mostly used unpack for multiple fields, and forgot about that detail.